# How to convert an RGB image to stright lines in python?

Tags: python, image-processing

I am trying to learn python by doing some small projects. one of them is as follows:
I want to write a code that converts an image to straight lines. I am actually into string art and want to receive the output in a way that can be used to easily build the string art by using the output of my code.
so, I'll try to explain what I'm trying to do:
1. import an image and get the pixel coordinate and save them into an array.
2.get brightness value for each pixel of the image. 
3. choose a number of lines that are going to be the "quality" of my output, in reality, they'd be the strings that I use to create the art.
4.draw a random amount of lines through the darkest pixel of the image, and compare each lines total brightness to the others, the darkest (the line hitting the darkest pixels) is chosen and the pixels in that line are removed from the pixel array.
5.save the two x and y coordinate of every line's intersection with the image borders ( my canvas). so I can use this later and know where to start and finish ny strings.
6. repeat the step 4 and 5, for the number of lines chosen.
7. print or save the XY coordinates of the line intersections with image borders.

I plan using PIL and numpy to do this, now my question is this:

a. do you think there are easier or better ways to active my goal?
b. what is the best way to get a clean array of pixels from any given digital image?

you can see the kind of image I'm trying to produce at linify.me

thanks.

Comment: Getting a "clean array of pixels" is the easy part. Pillow+NumPy will do that just fine. Other libraries could also do it just fine. None of them are going to do it any better than the others; barring the use of image formats they don't support, or bugs, they're all going to give you the exact same array of pixels.

Comment: Agree with abarnert just do: `from PIL import Image; import numpy as np; print(np.array(Image.open(filename)))` so basically just                                                                           `print(np.array(Image.open(filename)))`

Comment: `lignify.me` does not seem to be a valid URL. Could you post a complete link, or upload a picture, to get an idea of what you're trying to do? I have a hard time following your explanation, but it sounds really interesting!

Comment: thanks for the quick reply guys! I'll try that and report back. also sorry for the wrong url, I've corrected it. thank you!

Comment: Did you end up figuring how to do this? I am looking to do the same.